Is Srikantha Rudra mentioned in Shiva Puran? Is Srikantha rudra a lower form than SadaShiva?
As we know Lord Shiva is mentioned in various forms eg Kaalrudra, Srikantha Rudra, SadaShiva, Param Shiva.
So is Srikantha Rudra the name of Pauranik Shiva? Is Srikantha Rudra mentioned in Shiva Puran?
